# Vehicle shakes when accelerating

Tags: chevrolet, s10

I just bought a 2000 Chevy s10. It shakes when accelerating moderately in gears 3-5 (manual transmission). If I accelerate very gently, it doesn't happen. There is also a knocking noise every 1-2 seconds when it is shaking (it sounds like it's coming from the lower driver's side of the engine bay, but I can't be sure because it only happens when the vehicle is moving).

It accelerates fine in 1st and 2nd, so I don't think the transmission is slipping. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: You say "just bought" so did the car do this when you took it for a road test?  Why not take it back to the dealer and get them to sort it? It could possibly be an engine mount but also many other things,

Comment: @SolarMike Private party purchase.

Comment: @SolarMike How many other things? I'm not sure where to start looking, so I'm hoping for a list of things to check to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Check the U joints, if they are really bad you can move the driveshaft with your hand. If they are worn but real bad you have to remove the driveshaft  and manually rotate the U joints to feel for binding.

Comment: There's so many possibilities here, it could be worn tires, bad suspension, problems with the axle, the list goes on

Comment: My vote for the shaking problem would be on engine mounts. I wouldn't bother fixing the issue if it's minor, but from your question it sounds like it's not exactly minor due to the knocking noise. But the knock and shaking may be two different issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the U Joints. No other fixes were necessary to stop the noise or the vibration.